# Identify a transitive relation

Tags: c, algorithm, adjacency-matrix

I am writing a C program to find transitivity. In a 2D array, if  `adj[0][1] = 1`  and `adj[1][2] = 1`, I want to mark `adj[0][2]` also as `1`.  This should hold for any transitive relation in the matrix.

Please help me with some code for this.

```
    adj_matrix[j1][j2]=1;

    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if (adj_matrix[i][j1])
        adj_matrix[i][j2]=1;

    }
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(adj_matrix[j2][i])
        {
        adj_matrix[j1][i]=1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In general, people will help you when you've shown some evidence of having tried to help yourself.  A plain 'gimmedacodez' question is likely to be closed.  What have you tried?  Preferably, you should show us an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so we can help you with your problems.

Comment: HI as of now i have written the code like this.
say j1 and j2 are the row n column i want to mark.

Comment: It appears that you have a 26x26 array...it would be better to parameterize the size (maybe N).  You need to test two conditions: adj[i][j] = 1 and adj[j][k] = 1 (i ≠ j and j ≠ k) and set adj[i][k] to 1.  That smacks of three nested loops.

Comment: Thanks .. i am trying it .. hard coding 26 is intentional..

Comment: for(i=0;i<26;i++)
for(j=0;j<26;j++)
for(k=0;k<26;k++)
if(adj_matrix[i][j] && adj_matrix[j][k])
adj_matrix[i][k]=1;

Comment: @KiranBangalore, a triply-nested loop will not be sufficient because this will only show you the first level of transitive relations. Each transitive relation which is discovered could, itself, expose new transitive relations. My answer should account for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a "transitive closure algorithm"

The [Floyd-Warshall Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is a good example of one of these, though there are many (many) others such as [Johnson's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm). A quick search on Google Scholar will point you towards some of the other sources and more technical descriptions.

The code for the Floyd-Warshall algorithm in its original form (which finds the shortest paths between every connected point) is:

```
int dist[N][N];  // For some N
int i, j, k;
// Input data into dist, where dist[i][j] is the distance from i to j.
// If the nodes are unconnected, dist[i][j] should be infinity

for ( k = 0; k < N; k++ )
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
   dist[i][j] = min( dist[i][j], dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] );
```

Modifying this code for your use scenario gives:

```
int dist[N][N];  // For some N
int i, j, k;
// Input data into dist, where dist[i][j] is the distance from i to j.
// If the nodes are unconnected, dist[i][j] should be infinity

for ( k = 0; k < N; k++ )
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
   if(dist[i][k] && dist[k][j])
      dist[i][j] = 1;
```

Notice that the order of the subscripts here. Having the subscripts in this order fulfills a criterion of dynamic programming which ensures that the path is improved incrementally and is at all times optimal.

The time complexity is O(N^3).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work:

```
reachable_matrix = adj_matrix
length_of_path = 1

while(length_of_path < (N - 1)) {
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            tmp_matrix[i][j] = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
                tmp_matrix[i][j] ||= reachable_matrix[i][k] && reachable_matrix[k][j]; // Can I reach from i to j through k?
            }
        }
    }
    reachable_matrix = tmp_matrix;
    length_of_path *= 2;
}
```

As Richard commented, this is equivalent to calculating traversability of graph.

You can think of `adj_matrix[i][j]` as about a number saying how many paths of length 1 lead from from `i` to `j`. Then `adj_matrix ** l` (thats adjancency matrix to the power of `l`) tells you how many paths of length at least `l` there are between any two two nodes.

The inner loops in my code (looping with variables i, j and k) are basically multiplication of `reachable_matrix` by `reachable_matrix` and storing it in `tmp_matrix`, only instead of addition and multiplication I use logical or and and, because we're not interested in the exact number, only in its truth value.

Outer loop keeps squaring `reachable_matrix` while power to which it is raised (length of paths that we checked) is smaller than `N - 1`. Stopping at `N - 1` is enough, because if you have a path of this length, it means that you are visiting all nodes in the graph. Paths with more steps necessarily must contain cycles. On the other hand I don't perform binary exponentiation exactly to keep things simple (I think it would be a little less efficient, but I'm not sure about that) and because trying longer paths doesn't do any harm.

Overall this algorithm has complexity O(log(N) * N**3).

Comment: I thought about my answer some more and traversability was probably the wrong word: "transitive closure" is more accurate and, as it happens, there are a number of algorithms to solve the problem. Floyd-Warshall is perhaps the best known.

Comment: @cube . What modification should be done to the algorithm if "N" is varying? consider the biggest value of N?

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this is correct.

```
for(i=0;i<26;i++) 
for(j=0;j<26;j++)
for(k=0;k<26;k++)
if(adj_matrix[i][j] && adj_matrix[j][k])
adj_matrix[i][k]=1;
```

Comment: The indentation is tatty, but the logic looks correct (except perhaps for the testing of `i == j` and `j == k`; I'm not sure whether those matter).  Does it produce the answer you expected?  Do you know what answer you expected?  Wouldn't it be sensible to test the code on a 4x4 or 5x5 matrix before going for a 26x26 matrix?

Comment: Hi, it was a very simple logic.. i just confused with from algorithms like BFS. any ways was very helpful. thanks

Comment: Not correct; you will have misses when you have longer chains (adj[3][2], adj[2][1], adj[1][0] --> should set adj[3][0] but doesn't)

Comment: No, this is incorrect - but it is close! It does not fulfill the optimal substructure property of dynamic programming. My answer will point you to the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, which is subtly different from your answer, but produces the correct result.